# AS3 SecureSocket addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate not avaiable?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ssl, compiler-errors

I want to use the addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate() method of the SecureSocket to setup a connection to a HTTPS/SSL Webservice. But this method is not avaiable inside the flash platform. I got this error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate not found on flash.net.SecureSocket and there is no default value.
```

So I`m wondering. Is this method only avaiable when using Flash builder and Flex? I have Flash CS5 and Adobe air 3.8 installed.

I read the reference:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SecureSocket.html

They said you can use it, but it is not mentioned in the paragraph: "Public Methods"

Comment: It would appear to be a Air specific method.  See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/net/SecureSocket.html for details, where the method is listed as publicly available on the class.  Note the distinction between `window.runtime.flash.net.SecureSocket` and `flash.net.SecureSocket`

Comment: I installed Adobe Air 3.8 but still don't have the option. how can I integrate the package: window.runtime.flash.net.SecureSocket?

Answer (score 0):

you need to compile as an App (i.e. native binary for iOS or Android) not as Flash. Not all methods and classes are available to Flash (i.e. SWF for web)